# AngularJS Directives - specify defaults for callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, callback, default

I have a directive that takes a few methods as callbacks. All of them require attributes to work.

```
scope: {
    onEventOne: '&?',
    onEventTwo: '&?'
}

function someWork() {
    onEventOne()(myVar);
    onEventTwo()(myOtherVar);
}
```

My problem is when I don't have some of those callbacks defined, as they are not all required.

```
<div>
    <myDirective on-event-one="customHandler"></myDirective>
</div>
```

In the code above, when calling `onEventOne()(myVar);` everuthing works, but when calling `onEventTwo()(myOtherVar);` I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.
I tried using the link function to set a blank function as default,

```
function linkFunction(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (!attrs.onEventOne) {scope.onEventOne = scope.blankHandler;}
    if (!attrs.onEventTwo) {scope.onEventTwo = scope.blankHandler;}
}
```

but that causes the the default function to be called while still throwing `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

How do I set these default functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of your functions implies that `blankHandler` must return one more "blank" function (`angular.noop` is convenient here). This is what I would do in link function in your case:

```
var blankHandler = function() {
    return angular.noop;
};

if (!attrs.onEventOne) {scope.onEventOne = blankHandler;}
if (!attrs.onEventTwo) {scope.onEventTwo = blankHandler;}

scope.onEventOne()(myVar);
scope.onEventTwo()(myOtherVar);
```